# Does the conductance of a semiconducter change when the Fermi level $E_F$ stays the same, but the distance to the valence band $E_V$ increases?

Tags: semiconductor-physics

When talking about n-type semiconductors and assuming roomtemperature: Does only the Fermi level determine the conductance of the semiconductor or also the energy difference between the Fermi level and the valence band? So, is there a difference in conductance, when you compare situation (a) to situation (b)?

[image]

Comment: If the temperature is large enough to consider all donors to result in electrons in the conduction band, and the number of donors is much greater than the intrinsic carrier concentration, than it is reasonable to take the number of conduction electrons to be equal to the number of donors. (Now, since the semiconductor is different, other material effects come in to play to determine the actual conductance from that number of carriers).

Comment: @JonCuster I'm not sure, if you meant that how large the difference between the Fermi level and valence band was did or did not matter. Could you clarify that, please.

Comment: The relevant energy scale for moving electrons from the donor level to the conduction band is the 0.146eV noted in your drawing.

Comment: @JonCuster is your answer that the increased difference between the Fermi level and valence band does not decrease the conductivity?

Comment: Not exactly, no - factors beyond carrier concentration also impact conductivity, from what the real band structure is, to the phonon spectrum, to defect scattering to ...

Answer (score 0):

In general, in a semiconductor you have always both electrons in the conduction band and holes in the valence bands. Their densities are related by $$n·p=n_i^2$$ where the intrinsic density $n_i$ (which is the density of both electrons and holes when the Fermi level is about half the band gap) is related to the band gap $E_G$ by $$n_i^2=N_C\exp{-\frac{E_C-E_F}{kT}}N_V \exp{-\frac{E_F-E_V}{kT}}=N_c N_V \exp{-\frac{E_G}{kT}}$$ where $N_c$ and $N_V$ are the effective densities of state of the conduction and valence band, and $E_C$ and $E_V$ the conduction and valence band edges, respectively. Thus, the closer the Fermi level $E_F$ is to the conduction band, the higher the density of electrons there, and the lower the density of holes in the valence band. For usual n-type semiconductors like silicon with a not too small band gap, the Fermi level is very close to the conduction band, so that the hole density in the valence band is extremely small and thus can be neglected in the conductance. For example, at room temperature silicon has an intrinsic carrier density of about $$n_i=1·10^{10}cm^{-3}$$ When it has an n-type doping of $N_D=1·10^{16}cm^{-3}$, the electron concentration in the conduction band is $n≈1·10^{16}cm^{-3}$ and the hole density in the valence band is $p≈1·10^{4}cm^{-3}$ which is 12 orders of magnitude smaller than $n$.

Comment: So is your answer that the increased difference between the Fermi level and valence band does not decrease the conductivity?

Comment: @Okosa - You are right, the distance between Fermi level and valence band is already so large in the first case that you have practically no contribution to the conductance. Thus, in the larger band gap case, the contribution of holes to conductance is even more negligible.